# saving variables in formatted ASCII file

Tags: matlab, printf, ascii

I have calculated the skewness of an image using the following code.

```
X=imread(teddy.jpg);
I2 = im2double(X);
s=skewness(I2(:))
save('pqfile.txt','p','-ascii')
type('pqfile.txt')
```

I want that the `skewness` should be saved in the file pqfile.txt as

```
skweness1=(value of skwness)
```

Can any one tell me how do I attach the string with the value of the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html?refresh=true):

```
fid = fopen('pqfile.txt','w');
fprintf(fid,'skewness1=%f',s);
fclose(fid)
```

Comment: sir your code is absolutely,there is another doubt suppose I have created a GUI that lets the user select an image form a location(browsing)and then he clicks the skewness button to calculate the skewness,now when I run the program I select an Image Its Skewness is calculated and stored in a text file,again i browse another Image (but this time I do not run my file i directly click select image button),calculate the skewness but now the skweness of the previous image is overwritten.I want skewness of all the imgs I browse and be saved in the txt file by runing my code just once Please help me

Comment: @swatimishra That is deserving of a new question.  If you post a new question with that scenario, I'm sure some one will have suggestions.

Comment: OK ,that means u dont have the answer for this question sir?

Comment: @swatimishra Not as stated, no.  I think it would help for you to re-state your new question in a new post, with an example if possible.

Comment: actually I can't post a new question since I had just posted one, I can do that only after 90 mins... I'll post my code along with question.

Comment: @swatimishra Please wait and post a new question.  Q&A here are meant to be discrete and clear, and not evolving threads.  If the question needs to change significantly after being answered, it should not be changed and a new question asked.